# How to re-trigger (choke) a sound using web audio api

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I'm curious how I can do something called a "choke" in web audio api. When I play a sound using a key, if that key is pressed again, I want it to stop the sound and play it again. Any idea how to do this?

My code so far:

```
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
console.log(e);
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 81:  // Q 
        playKick(BUFFERS.kick);
    break;
}
})

function playKick(instrument) {
    source1 = context.createBufferSource();
    source1.buffer = instrument;
    source1.loop = true;
    source1.connect(context.destination);
    if (!source1.start)
      source1.start = source1.noteOn;
    source1.start(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep a reference to the currently-playing sound. So that needs to be available outside the scope of `playKick`. Then, within `playKick`, you call `stop` or `noteOff` on the old sound before creating the new one and assigning it to that global var.

Something like:

```
var current;

$(document).on('keydown', function( e ) {
  console.log(e);
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 81:
      playKick(BUFFERS.kick);
    break;
  }
});

function playKick( instrument ) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = instrument;
  source.loop = true;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  if ( current ) {
    if ( !current.stop ) {
      current.stop = current.noteOff;
    }
    current.stop(0);
  }
  if ( !source.start ) {
    source.start = source.noteOn;
  }
  source.start(0);
  current = source;
}
```

Granted, there are certainly better ways to organize this — but hopefully this'll get you started.